# PIC Processor, SPI to microSD card, 25Mhz Clock slew is bad

Tags: pic, spi

Using a PIC24 processor which has a rated SPI clock speed of 25Mhz, we see quite a jaggered sort of wave for the clock, instead of nice square pulses. Given the spec is rated to the speed we are using, it is not clear what the problem is.

Slowing it right down and the pulses come nice and clean, but we don't get the speed we need.

It works at the higher speed so the clock cant be that bad, but we just get issues now and then which is unclear if its electrical yet, but I thought I would post here to narrow that argument down a bit.

Tracks on the PCB are short, we have maybe 10-15mm total of tracks between the processor and the microSD socket, no capacitors on the lines. No wires, all PCB tracks only. This is operating as SPI mode, not SD mode.

What could cause this?
Bad Slew I know can be from capacitance, or if the driver is not up to the task of driving what is connected, but this is just a microSD card.

This was measured with a battery powered isolated 200Mhz Hantek scope, with a 100:1 probe. I know some of this could be potentially from the scope loading the lines, which is why I used a 100:1 probe rather than a 10:1, and it certainly is better using the 100:1 but its still not as I would expect. Next would be to get an Active Probe I guess, but really I am not sure that is going to be possible, but it would indicate what is really going on I guess.

Should the pulses be nice and sharp and square at this frequency?

Pics of 10:1 and 100:1 probes attached.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Regards
J

Comment: Did you compensate your probes correctly?

Comment: Yes thanks, the probes were compensated and calibrated with the scope square wave, they were correct. Just checked now, still correct.

Answer (score 3):

That waveform doesn’t look too bad - the ringing is normal and isn’t enough to be a false trigger. If it bothers you add a damping resistor at the PIC side of 22-33 ohms. And measure at the SD card itself, not the PIC.

In any event, when taking a scope measurement where signal integrity is a concern, make sure you have a very short ground on scope lead, next to the probe point if possible. This makes a large difference in how much ringing will be present.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this resistor. But yes, the probe ground was right next to the pin being measured. Everything is very close together.